# Lyx change the color of Math panel

Tags: color, lyx

is there a way for me to change the color (the blue part of the img below) of the math panel? My lyx is in dark-mode which I like. The only my un-satisfaction is coming from the blue part. I would like to change its color to red. I've known that I can change color format at Lyx>Preferences>Look & Feel. But I've tried several items and still did not find the answer. Is it possible or not possible? Thanks.
[image]

Use Lyx 2.4.0. You can download below. Thank scottkosty for suggesting. Dark mode looks much better here.
http://ftp.lyx.org/ftp/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.4/

One thing I suggest is to improve Table Panel here:
Table Toggle Icon panel is not visible well enough. Other than that, it looks good.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in the current LyX release.

In LyX 2.4.0 (release date unknown), there are improvements specifically for the math panel: https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX24#darkmode

Comment: Thanks. LyX 2.4.0 looks much better! Please vote for up guys. I don't have enough reputation ....yet ... I will when I reach 15

Comment: @Python2018 If you like to live dangerously, you can join our lyx-users mailing list and when it is available you can test out the test version of 2.4.0 and give feedback. If interested, you can subscribe here: http://lists.lyx.org/mailman/listinfo/lyx-users

Comment: @Python2018 Which version did you install and with which OS or linux distribution ? I could not install it. On arch linux (endeavourOS) I tried `./configure` then `make` then `make install` but I recieved the error : `error: ‘strlen’ was not declared in this scope
 230 |                         start += strlen("language=");`.

Comment: @userrandrand I think that error might be from compiling an older LyX commit with a newer compiler. Do you get that error when trying to compile current master branch? I would guess not. Also, you might want to try CMake instead of autotools. Both work fine so if one doesn't work give the other a try. If you are trying to compile and older commit, you might need to cherry pick compiler fixes. Just a shot in the dark, but maybe this one will do it for you: `git cherry-pick --keep-redundant-commits -x -X theirs "b73ab025"`.

Comment: @scottkosty Hi thanks for your help. By the current master branch you mean the  lyx git page ? Using  `git clone git://git.lyx.org/lyx` I got a Connection timed out error message.

Comment: I am using arch but go easy on me with the linux commands haha. At which stage should I use the `git cherry-pick` command ? Should I use it with `Cmake`, somewhere after `./configure` ?

Comment: @userrandrand sorry for not giving explanations! The `git` command is after you clone the repository, before your run `cmake`. I suggest you join lyx-devel mailing list: https://www.lyx.org/MailingLists#toc3 We will be happy to walk you through compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite relieved to have found a work around. Following: [this kde reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/9ciyqv/kde_how_to_change_specific_app_theme/?sort=new).

One can simply copy the color settings of another theme (In the kde desktop environment I can just copy the whole file, not sure if that works with gnome or another desktop environment) (in kde for me this was in ~/.local/share/color-schemes).

Then one can paste the copied text at the end of the lyxrc file in ~/.config, save the file and that's it.